# Selenium IDE wont click on dynamic id

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm having trouble getting a link clicked on Selenium IDE.

The id is picked from the itteration in a while loop but i can't get the ID echo'ed in somehow.

This is my code:

```
<tr>
<td>open</td>
<td>/list</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>storeAllLinks</td>
<td>linkArray</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>getEval</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>index</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>while</td>
<td>index &lt; 10;</td><!-- should be array length but that wont word eighter, problem for later -->
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>clickAndWait</td>
<td>id=${index}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>getEval</td>
<td>index++;</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>pause</td>
<td>1000</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>endWhile</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Anny clues on whats going wrong would be great help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: i tried these options:
id=${index},
javascript{echo 'ID='; echo index;},
id=index. But they all throw an execption: index is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You can locate link by its text. Use of `Xpath` and `link text` might help you.

Or please share part of HTML.

Comment: the HTML is just a <ul> containing a variable amound of <li>'s that each contain an <a> with an incrementing id from 0 to however long the list is -1.